# Add nodes with attributes to graph from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, networkx

So I have a dictionary and I want to input the keys as nodes into a graph. Then the values of the keys in the dictionary, they have to become attributes of the node. This is my code right now.

```
dictionary = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}
G.nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(dictionary.keys(), attribute = dictionary.values())
G.nodes[1]
>> {'attribute': dict_values(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
```

This is not the desired output. I actually only want 'a' as attribute from key 1. Desired output is:

```
G.nodes[1]
>> {'attribute': 'a'}
```

So the problem is in assigning my attributes. But how can I do this right?

Answer (score 3):

To assign attributes to individual nodes, use `G.add_edges_from(X)` where `X` is a list (or other container) of tuples of the form `(node, attribute_dict)`.  So you need to create the attribute dictionary for each node.  Let's use a list comprehension for that.

```
G.add_nodes_from([(node, {'attribute': attr}) for (node, attr) in dictionary.items()])
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't find an answer straight as a `networkx` function. However the following code works.

```
dictionary = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(dictionary.keys())
for key,n in G.nodes.items():
   n["attribute"]=dictionary[key]
```

Then you can see the attributes of each one.

```
G.nodes[1]
#result {'attribute': 'a'}
```